# Google's BottomSheet appears at top of screen

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-design-library, bottom-sheet

I'm using android's new BottomSheet inside Design Library.
Problem is that I'm using it inside a Fragment and It cause that it appear at top of screen instead of appearing at bottom.

This is my Activity xml:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="ir.aidinsoft.quicktaxi.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tlbr_acMain"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/crdl_acMain"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tlbr_acMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nscv_acMain"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- This Layout Is Replacement Layout For Fragment -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/frml_acMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And This Is My Fragment xml:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ir.aidinsoft.quicktaxi.MyFragment">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/rvfl_frTaxi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/frag_frTaxi_map"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/facb_frTaxi_request"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- My Bottom Sheet Layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frml_frTaxi_bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So after Replacing Fragment in Layout with this code:

```java
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frml_acMain,  taxiFragment).commit();
```

I adde this code to reveal BottomSheet on FAB clicked state. 
Java Code for Fragment:

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.facb_frTaxi_request);
    bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.frml_frTaxi_bottomSheet);
    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });
}
```

What is the problem? what I'm doing wrong?
TnQ

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @Firat  in my case it was because of `animateLayoutChanges` animation.

Comment: @SamanSattari You may want to consider adding it as the answer to your question. I just had the same issue, and removing `animateLayoutChanges` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `animateLayoutChanges` inside your layout, removing it can fix your problem.